# "Inject data from server" into a React app's index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to "inject data from the server into the page", as [per create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) instead of hardcoding environment variables at build time:

> To read them at **runtime**, you would need to load HTML into memory on the server and replace placeholders in runtime, as [described here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags#injecting-data-from-the-server-into-the-page).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      window.SERVER_DATA = __SERVER_DATA__;
    </script>
```

> Then, on the server, **you can replace `__SERVER_DATA__`** with a JSON of real data right before sending the response.

---

I've got an `index.html` file which I'd like to inject URLs from environment variables into, using a backend application which serves the static/built file.

For example, in `index.html`:

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Runs before react application.
    window.SERVICE_A_URL = "<%=SERVICE_A_URL%>";
    window.SERVICE_B_URL = "<%=SERVICE_B_URL%>";
    console.log(window.SERVICE_A_URL, window.SERVICE_B_URL);
  </script>
```

My backend application (e.g. express) should inject `SERVICE_A_URL=https://service_a.example.com` into `<%=SERVICE_A_URL%>`.

However, I **cannot** do this because when my React app builds, it finds this template `"<%=SERVICE_A_URL%>"` and decides not to generate the `index.html` file. So I can't use ejs. I need to use something like `__SERVER_DATA__`, not `<%=SERVER_DATA%>`. But what tool can I use to replace this at runtime? For example, in an express server.

---

**Extra details:**

Why?: The other/better approach is to make a network request to an API server to get the URLs dynamically. However, the application I'm working with would need a lot of refactoring to support this. I'll probably end up searching for **ENV_VAR** in the index.html and modifying it.

NodeJS app

```js
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';
import ejs from 'ejs';

const app = express();
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);

const renderIndexHtmlWithServiceUrls = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.render('index.html', {
        SERVICE_A_URL: process.env.SERVICE_A_URL,
        SERVICE_B_URL: process.env.SERVICE_B_URL,
        cache: true
    })
}
app.get('/', renderIndexHtmlWithServiceUrls)
app.get('/index.html', renderIndexHtmlWithServiceUrls)

// Serve built react app
app.use(express.static("/build"));

...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Overview:

I just ended up creating a `mutated_index.html` file when the backend (expressJS) application launches. Then I serve that to all clients when they request `/` or `/index.html`. This backend application also serves the react production files.

- Load original index.html
- For each substitution I want to do:

  - `modified = modified.replace(substitutionKey, substitute);`
- Write new `mutated_index.html` to disk.
- Serve `mutated_index.html` in `app.get("/", ...)` and `app.get("/index.html", ...)`

  - **Below** this, serve the other files: `app.use(express.static("/build"));`

### Long term solution

If you have this problem, I would suggest you refactor your application to avoid global variables if you need this functionality. Then you can make network requests and instantiate services/clients when you get the data you need.